# Group List by property

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a `List` of purchases that looks something like this:

```
List<MyItem> l = new List<MyItem>();
l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 1, person_name = "Jim", shirt = "green", cost = 10});
l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 1, person_name = "Jim", shirt = "yellow", cost = 20});
l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 1, person_name = "Jim", shirt = "blue", cost = 30});
l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 2, person_name = "John", shirt = "red", cost = 40});
l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 2, person_name = "John", shirt = "orange", cost = 50});
l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 3, person_name = "Joe", shirt = "purple", cost = 60});
```

I want to be able to group the shirt purchases in the list by person so that I can loop through and display what each person purchased, something like:

```
foreach(person in people)
{
    Display(p.person_id);
    Display(p.person_name);
    
    foreach(purchase in p.purchases)
    {
            Display(purchase.shirt);
            Display(purchase.cost);
    }
}
```

I suspect LINQ has a group option that will work for me but I'm not sure what that would look like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq's `GroupBy()` function takes a `KeySelector` usually this is just a property of the `Enumerable<T>` T's type, however you can use anonymous types here and group by multiple properties in this case the person's Id and Name.
e.g.

```
var groupedList = l.GroupBy(x => new { x.person_id, x.person_name });
```

You can then enumerate through the grouping, with the `Key` containing the Id and Name of the person.

**Partial solution:**

```
public static void Main()
    {
        List<MyItem> l = new List<MyItem>();
        l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 1, person_name = "Jim", shirt = "green", cost = 10});
        l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 1, person_name = "Jim", shirt = "yellow", cost = 20});
        l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 1, person_name = "Jim", shirt = "blue", cost = 30});
        l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 2, person_name = "John", shirt = "red", cost = 40});
        l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 2, person_name = "John", shirt = "orange", cost = 50});
        l.Add(new MyItem(){person_id = 3, person_name = "Joe", shirt = "purple", cost = 60});
        
        var groupedList = l.GroupBy(x => new { x.person_id, x.person_name });
        foreach(var groupedItem in groupedList)
        {
            Display(groupedItem.Key.person_id);
            Display(groupedItem.Key.person_name);
            
            foreach(var item in groupedItem)
            {
                Display(item.shirt);
                Display(item.cost);
            }
        }
    }
```

netFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bHc7In